# Realm migration using assetFile()

Tags: android, realm, realm-migration

I've followed the [instructions on migration](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#migrations) at Realm's website and use `assetFile()` in my Realm configuration. Yet it appears the migrated realm is empty as any query returns zero items, when it should return at least one.

Many examples with `assetFile()` are either old or incorrect. Can anyone provide a full example on how to use a .realm file in Android Assets folder, and use it on first-install?

Comment: You can see in [Realm's androidTest](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/tree/3cbc084b3c888e9555629638e31adebbfd369c8f/realm/realm-library/src/androidTest) that they have a Realm file in `assets/asset_file.realm`, and they have [a configuration built with](https://github.com/realm/realm-java/blob/47adef18250eb0a302daa22bad20d3ede96277e8/realm/realm-library/src/androidTest/java/io/realm/RealmConfigurationTests.java#L898) `.assetFile("asset_file.realm")`

Comment: Thanks @EpicPandaForce. The test code pointed me in the right direction. One mistake in the process was creating the RealmObject manually instead of letting the Realm Browser do that properly...